# Javascript to capitalize the next char after " Mc"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Given a string like `Marty Mcfly` is there a regex or other one line solution to capitalize the 'f' so I get `Marty McFly`?

I can always count on the space between first and last and the first letter of the last name (i.e. the M) will always be caps.

I'm pretty open to just about any javascript, jquery, regex solution, I just need it to be short and sweet.

I've got a method that takes the string apart using indexOf and substring but I'm hoping theres a regex or something similar.

Comment: Will it need to work for Mac as well? What about O'Connor, etc? DeVille? Compare O'Connor with D'eath. What's your scope?

Comment: Good questions.  Yes it would be nice if it worked on a mac.  I've got the o'conner etal covered with another regex.  Hadn't though of DeVille though I don't know how you'd tell that apart from any name that starts with "De" so we'll survive without it.

Comment: +1 for nice, cross-platform regex question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can take advantage of the form of `String.replace` which takes a function as its second argument:

```js
function fixMarty(s) {
  return (""+s).replace(/Mc(.)/g, function(m, m1) {
    return 'Mc' + m1.toUpperCase();
  });
}
fixMarty('Marty Mcfly'); // => "Marty McFly"
fixMarty("Mcdonald's"); // => "McDonald's"
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a perfect case for using a callback with `.replace()`.

```
function fixMc(str) {
    return(str.replace(/\bMc(\w)/, function(match, p1) {
        return(match.slice(0, -1) + p1.toUpperCase());
    }));
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Qbf8R/ where you can see it in action on a several different test cases.

By way of explanation for the how the callback works, the parameter `match` is the whole regex match, the parameter `p1` is what the first parenthesized group matched and the callback returns what you want to replace the whole regex match with.

Comment: never thought of using slice like that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of RegEx's `exec` method and String's `replace` method:

```
var name = 'Marty Mcfly',
    pattern = /\bmc([a-z])/gi,
    match = pattern.exec(name);

if (match) {
    alert(name.replace(pattern, 'Mc' + match[1].toUpperCase()));
}
```

Here's a version that works with "Mac":

```
var name = 'Connor Macleod',
    pattern = /\b(mc|mac)([a-z])/gi,
    match = pattern.exec(name);

if (match) {
    alert(name.replace(pattern, match[1] + match[2].toUpperCase()));
}
```

Comment: +1 for your first answer...correct me if I'm wrong but the second one would get screwed up with a name like "Shane Mack" right?  We decided we'd live with the little quirks like this we just wanted to hit some of the main things.  Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 2):

```
var text = 'Marty Mcfly';
text = text.replace(/Mc[a-z]/, function (k)
    {
      return 'Mc' + k[2].toUpperCase();
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best I can do:

```
'Marty Mcfly'.replace(/ mc([a-z])/i, function (str, $1) {return  " Mc" + $1.toUpperCase()})
```